# Django Generic Views Date-Based URLconf

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-generic-views

Trying to teach myself Django but running into a snag.
Generic Views seem to be a great idea but I personally find the documentation a little cryptic  at times (maybe I'm being prissy).
So I have been trying to use the Date Based generics views in and specifically ArchieveIndexView.

I have even attempted following some non-djangoproject.com examples and still have problems.
I used the example provided at [this site.](http://martinogden.me/2011/03/27/quick-look-django-13-class-based-views/)

Here is my current `project/urls.py`.
I am also at this point, not worrying about pattern matching, just trying to get it to work.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView
from blog.models import Entry

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ArchiveIndexView.as_view('date_field': 'pub_date', 'queryset': Entry.objects.all())),

    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

With this setup I keep receiving a Invalid Syntax error at the line describing ArchiveIndexView class.
If I comment out this line the problem goes away. If I decouple the URLs to their appropriate app I get the same error.

The error suggest I just have something out of place, a comma or something but I have yet to conclude what it is.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah.  I solved my own question thanks to a little pushing from shiva.

The dictionary works but only for the `extra_content` argument.
It was just done like that on the website I was trying to copy and for extra content in the documentation so I kept overlooking that glaringly obvious problem.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView
from blog.models import Entry

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ArchiveIndexView.as_view(date_field='pub_date', queryset=Entry.objects.all())),

    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Just needed to sleep on it...

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.dates import ArchiveIndexView
from blog.models import Entry

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ArchiveIndexView.as_view({'date_field': 'pub_date', 'queryset': Entry.objects.all()})),

    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

You seem to forget the {} brace required for dict in url(r'^$', ArchiveIndexView.as_view('date_field': 'pub_date', 'queryset': Entry.objects.all())),
line.